# Using XOM with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.5, xml-parsing, xom

I am attempting to install XOM so I can use it in my Java apps. The only problem is, I don't know where I can place it so NetBeans can find it. It would make sense to put it where the other .classes files are, but I can't seem to find them either.

The README file for XOM says to install it to the Classpath variable, but I don't know what that is.

So, how do I install XOM, and what is "Classpath"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NetBeans Library Manager (Tools|Libraries) to create a new library, add the Xom jar file (and all dependencies) to it and use this library in a new Java project.
To do this, use the Properties dialog for the project, navigate to the libraries page, and choose your new Xom library using "Add Library..."